# Rails Routing - How to create sub categories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I think I am really confused on how to route in rails. I tried reading the rails guides along with several other books and can't seem to figure this one out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Below is what I am trying to do:

1. I want to have a directory of books.
2. The directory will have many categories
3. Each of the categories will have many titles.
4. I need the url to look something like the following:
   http://www.mybooksite.com/books/history # I would like this to list all history books.
   http://www.mybooksite.com/books/history/Abraham-lincoln-Biography # this will be the book profile.

I need the directory to be SEO friendly so I am planning on using the gem friendly-id.

I also need each of the categories to have a static URL.

Thanks to whoever can point me in the right direction :)

Comment: Maybe start here? http://ruby.railstutorial.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need help with the routing, this should get you started...

```
resources :books do
  resource :history
end
```

Learn more here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Hi Donovan, thanks for the comment. Do you think you could provide me with a little more information?

Comment: @user2611695 he linked you the guide to rails routing as well as an example of nested resources. what "little more information" are you looking for?

Comment: So would I need to create a history controller? or would I create a static page?

Comment: in this example, you would need a `HistoryController`.

Comment: Thank you Donovan and Paul. I really appreciate the help.